# VideoJS: Videosize on an iPad

Tags: ios, html, video, html5-video, video.js

I am using VideoJS to show a video. It works great in all browsers on each and every system. Exception is the iPad (iOS 5 and iOS 6, both tested on Safari and Chrome). The video resizes to about 300px width.

When i delete videoJS from the page, the video is shown correctly. But i need videoJS for skinning purposes and because it makes HTML5 video work in jQuery sliders.

I tried several things:

- Manually entering width and height in video.js or JS.
- Adding CSS (including !important) to the videotag and even all tags (param) below.
- Tried some vague techniques i found on stackoverflow. Like -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; in the video-tag.
- Tried to play with wmode.

Nothing seems to work. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Are you specifying the width in and height in the video tag?

Comment: Yes, that and css, both. I tried to switch them on and off with no result. I also tried o edit he JS and add th parameters in there. Without luck.

Comment: Is there a way to overrule every setting when it comes to width and height in videojs? I think, somewhere down the road the width and height are either removed or rewritten. It wirks without videojs..

Answer (score 0):

First, if you haven't yet, you may want to upgrade to v4.0, released at the beginning of May (2013).

With 4.0, you can see a few examples of setting the width height, that are at least working for me on my iPad:
Width/Height 100%: http://jsbin.com/uyelud/1/edit
Width 200px/900px (weird dimension for example) http://jsbin.com/ojajuc/2/edit

To walk you through the vjs code...

The width height settings are grabbed from the tag here:
https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/v4.0.3/src/js/player.js#L112

Removed from the video tag (because it's wrapped by a container div and made to fill the container)
https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/v4.0.3/src/js/player.js#L144

Applied to the container div
https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/v4.0.3/src/js/player.js#L180

And then handled by the UI component code
https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/v4.0.3/src/js/component.js#L647

If you have different results on your page, you may want to set up a [reduced test case](http://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/) to help narrow it down.